# Contents header returns after first chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer

I am using `\documentclass{book}` and `tocloft` for the table of contents.

The way my document is structured I have the table of contents, then a `\chapter*`, then part one, chapters, etc.

For some reason, the "CONTENTS" header is on the blank page after the `\chapter*` finishes. If I change that chapter to `\chapter{Prologue}` instead of `\chapter*{Prologue}`, it's fine (but I don't want that chapter numbered).

Any idea what's going on here or how to make it

```
\clearpage

\setlength\cftparskip{-2pt}
\setlength\cftbeforesecskip{1pt}
\setlength\cftaftertoctitleskip{18pt}
\tableofcontents

\clearpage
% fixme: ``Contents'' still shows up on the header after prologue

\chapter*{Prologue}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Prologue}
% Prologue goes here

\clearpage

\part*{Part One}
% and so on...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User `\markboth` to set the header entry for a starred, unnumbered chapter, such as

```
\chapter*{Prologue}
\markboth{Prologue}{Prologue}
```

You also could apply your header formatting here, such as `\MakeUppercase{Prologue}` if required. Also, if you use the title "Prologue" very often now, it could be a good idea to make a macro for that name.

Comment: +1 It seems strange that it doesn't do that automatically, doesn't it? Thanks a lot!